# How do I select a focus point on the Nikon D5000?

Tags: nikon, focus, camera-controls, nikon-d5000, focus-point-selection

My Nikon D5000 has 11 selectable focus points but shamefully I don't know how to choose another point other than the center point.

How can I do this?

Am I misunderstanding concepts?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a decision about where in the image the focus point should be or how to tell the camera you'd like to use a focus point other than the center?

Comment: I am asking how to switch from a focus point to another during half-pressing of the shutter release button. If I understood right...

Comment: First of all camera should NOT be in AUTO mode. It wont let you chose the focus point. Second as already said below, select Single point AF and then chose the focus point by moving D pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to set the AF area mode to Single or Dynamic on your LCD display. Then you select the point using the D-pad. You can quickly return to the centre point by pressing the OK button.

The difference between Single and Dynamic is that Single keeps the focus point wherever you put it, whereas Dynamic will try and automatically keep the object originally focused on in focus by selecting other focus points automatically.

Also note that if your metering mode is set to Matrix or Center-Weighted, you are still metering the whole scene (with a center bias in CW's case), not the selected focus point. Set your metering to Spot to meter from the selected point.

Comment: what is the D-Pad?

Comment: The circular control to the right of the LCD display that you use to navigate the menus etc. It has four arrows on it and the OK button is in the centre.

Comment: What is the D-Pad ?
i did and understand everything exept for using the D-Pad ! what is it ? thank you :)

Comment: This has been answered immediately above your question...